# Using Gridview for metro apps

Tags: c#, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am working on Windows Store application using C#,
Right now I working on `FileOpenPicker`

```
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".epub");
files = await fileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
      fileNames.Append(file.Name);
}
ItemGridView2.Items.Add(fileNames.ToString());
```

After getting these files I want to place in Gridview, which have to display the name of the filenames in webview, For this I didn't get any idea to do it.

```
   <GridView x:Name="OutputgridView" Margin="185,182,0,0">
        <GridViewItem x:Name="item1" Height="144" Width="556"/>
    </GridView>
```

Can any one help for this,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope it can help you.

```
List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
...
foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
      fileList.Add(file.Name);
}
OutputgridView.ItemSource = fileList;
```

xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="OutputgridView" Margin="185,182,0,0">
       <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

xaml  2, you can do whatever you want in the DataTemplate:

```
<GridView x:Name="OutputgridView" Margin="185,182,0,0">
       <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" >
       <Image Source="" />
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
       </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It is working Fine,
I wonder to put an image for the Gridview Items,
Why because it is not even look good, the gridview didn't have proper alignment.

Comment: you can change the datatemplate to do it, like this . @kumar

Comment: Using datatemlapte I am trying load image from assets folder, like this
`<DataTemplate x:Name="ItemDataview" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True" >
   <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
     <Image Source="Assets/60Mint.png" Height="60" Width="60"      VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>`

there is any why do achieve this.

It is displaying with name only.

Thanks

Comment: try this <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/60Mint.png" .../>. @kumar